# Inject service into angular 1.5 component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, components

I'm trying to initialize a `test.service.js` from an angular1.5 component and I don't really know how to that. I have used this structure for angular components:

```
var testComponent =  {
    templateUrl: "app/components/test.component.html",
    controllerAs: "mvm",
    bindings:{
        bindingInput: "=",
},
controller: function(){
      var mvm = this;

    }
};
angular.module('myApp').component('testComponent', testComponent);
```

Comment: @31piy yes ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just inject it using the controller as following :

```
...
},
controller: ['testService', function(testService){
  var mvm = this;
}],
...
```

Comment: @mcmwhfy can you share your `test.service.js` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the service right into the controller like this:

```
....
    controller: function(testService) {
      var mvm = this;
    }
};
```

To prevent `testService` getting obfuscated by a minification plugin, let the injector service know about the dependencies as well.

```
var Controller = function(testService) {
   // Your controller code here
};

Controller.$inject = ['testService'];

var testComponent = {
  ...
  controller: Controller, // Assign controller in component
  ...
};
```

Comment: I receive an "testService is not defined" :|

Comment: @mcmwhfy -- what's the name of the service you declared in `test.service.js`?